# How can I get Modern Combat 2 to run on a Pandigital Novel?

Tags: technical-issues, android

I installed it like normal, then ran it.  It wanted to download some first-run data so it took 4-5 mins doing that.  Then I got a screen that said "Download complete.  Tap OK to play."  I tapped OK and the screen went black.  A few seconds later it went back to my home screen.  All additional attempts to open it have resulted in the black screen followed by home.  Any suggestions?

My device is a [Pandigital Novel](http://www.pandigital.net/pandigitalnovel) running Android.  I did NOT get the app from Gameloft.

Note: Modern **Combat**, not Modern **Warfare**.  This question is about [the app](http://www.androidsoft4u.com/games/details-of-Modern-Combat-2Black-Pegasus-v10-for-Android.aspx), not Call of Duty.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?  Is this against the FAQs?  Is it poorly written?  If so, how could it be improved?  Last time I asked on MSO, "too obvious" is NOT a good reason for downvoting.  Of course, things could have changed over the course of a week.

Comment: Last I checked, peoples downvotes are theirs to spend as they please. They cost them reputation as well as you, and their purpose is to express whether they feel a question or answer is a good one. This is entirely independent of whether they feel the question *deserves to be on the site at all* or is, for instance, on or off topic, an opinion which is better served by a close vote or flag.

Comment: @Less: Yes, I am aware that people are free to use downvotes how they please.  I just get a bit distressed when people downvote me without comment.  To me it's like they're saying "You're not good but I won't tell you how to get better."

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz To be clear, peoples' down-votes cannot be "theirs to spend as they please" and also "entirely independent of whether they feel the question deserves to be on the site at all".  Many people (though not I, in this case) choose to down-vote questions in place of, or along with, voting or flagging to close.  I'm not aware of any limitation imposed by the system against this behavior, as of yet.

Comment: @JohntheGreen While I agree with your sentiment, this is an issue that has been often raised and always shot down (generally with some extent of understandable justification) in Meta - users will not be forced to explain their down-votes.  It's just something we have to live with.

Answer (score 4):

You have a Pandigital Novel.  I.e., it's a low-end device that can't run a game like MC2 and is  not supported.  [They only support high-end Samsung, Motorola, HTC and Sony devices](http://www.gameloft.com/android-hd-games/).  From their [FAQ](http://www.gameloft.com/faq/#10):

> **My phone isn't listed; can I order the
>   game for a different phone and use it
>   on mine?**
>
> If your phone doesn't appear on
>   Gameloft's site, it is not supported.
>   Picking an alternate phone, even if
>   the model numbers are similar, will
>   not work. Before adding a phone, we
>   perform various tests to make sure
>   that we can maintain the quality that
>   gamers expect from Gameloft.  However,
>   we regularly add new phones to our
>   website. If your phone isn't listed on
>   the site, please check back regularly.
>   If it's a popular phone, it's likely
>   we will add it as soon as we can.

Get a refund if you can.

Comment: Link fixed.  The point of it was just to distinguish from COD.

Comment: Removed that bit.  Answer still valid.